# EFI Shell version 2.60 [5.12]

Tags: command-line, 20.04, hard-drive, hardware

Yesterday I run normally my Ubuntu on my Laptop.
Today I'm getting this error instead of graphical enviroment

```
EFI Shell version 2.60 [5.12]
Current running mode 1.1.2
map: Cannot find required map name.

Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh, any other key to continue.

Shell>
```

Is it a hardware or software issue; how can I fix it ?

**EDIT** The Laptop is also very hot by now.